# Handle Class to avoid copies - problematic?

Tags: matlab

```matlab
classdef DataContainer < handle
    properties
        d
    end
end
```

```matlab
my_cells = DataContainer();
my_cells.d = cell(1, 100);
func(my_cells)
updated_data = my_cells.d{1:5};
```

Issues with such an approach? Seems too good. I'm only concerned with speed (and memory only if garbage collection fails).

The context is passing a data structure around to helper functions, without having to rewrite everything into a class. I'm aware there's property access overhead - i.e. `my_cells.d{1}` is slower than `d{1}` by itself would've been - but suppose that's acceptable.

Example issue, I've heard that once `.m` files are compiled into an optimized format, we want classes with fixed data types. (I imagine bypassing this by pre-initializing all possible containers - don't know if valid, but maybe separate topic.)

Comment: MATLAB is good at not making copies (internally, at runtime) which aren't required where data doesn't actually change in memory when being passed between functions. Do you have a [mcve] of a problem you're actually trying to solve with this approach?

Comment: The data is guaranteed to change. MRE, take `dictionary` of `cell`s, load it up with small arrays, and update their values with two helper functions in a loop of size 200.

Comment: Where did you hear this claim that “once .m files are compiled into an optimized format, we want classes with fixed data types”? I’ve never heard this, I wonder where it comes from.

Comment: @CrisLuengo A MathWorks software engineer. If you have a dispute, I could pass it along.

Comment: I don’t have a dispute. I just said I hadn’t heard it before. I’d love to learn more. Do you have a link to that discussion?

Comment: It was shared privately. I don't recall the details and can't readily find it, but I'll consider asking again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The context is passing a data structure around to helper functions, without having to rewrite everything into a class.

Just use a struct. This is what structs are designed to do, and they do it well. It will be faster, it will make more sense to the reader, and you won’t have that extra file defining a useless class.

If you need to modify the struct within the function, then the struct is both an input and an output argument.

Handle classes are meant to own resources that cannot be copied (or would be too expensive to copy). That is their purpose. For example MATLAB’s graphics: each window and every other one of the graphical elements on the screen are owned by a handle object. Each object corresponds to one of those objects. Copying the object would duplicate the graphical element on the screen, which you cannot do. Deleting the object deletes the graphical element on the screen. If your object has a similar function (maybe it owns an open file, or a network connection) then a handle class is the right way to define that object.

MATLAB’s regular syntax makes input arguments to a function immutable. When you call `func(a)`, you expect `a` will not change. Handle classes break this expectation, and therefore must be used with caution. Using them *to break the expectation* is just a terrible idea, you are making your code hard to read.

99% of examples in the docs that use a class make it into a handle class. This is wrong, and has normalized the use of handle classes for purposes where a value class is much more appropriate. I am certain that it was Java-trained programmers with little MATLAB experience that wrote those examples. And it makes me sad to read them.

Comment: I was going to go into a tirade about how OOP code is awful, and not at all what the original idea of OOP intended, but I’ll shut up here.

Comment: Acceptable workaround, but I'll keep the question open to _performance_ examples of why classes are bad. _"Handle classes own resources that cannot be copied"_ - this I don't understand; at the end of everything, I could do `out = my_cells.d` and return that (or start with `out = DataContainer()`). If `struct` is superior in speed, that's nearly ideal, but having to specify a return may cause more trouble than the performance cost solves.

Comment: And, of course, "classes are slower" _is_ sufficient - I'll accept the answer as-is eventually.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon “having to specify a return may cause more trouble than the performance cost solves.” That is MATLAB syntax. If you break that by (ab)using handle classes to change a function’s input arguments, you make your code harder to read. I strongly recommend you do not do that.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I’ve updated the text on handle classes where it was not clear.

Comment: I've understood the original, but it's a "clean code" problem, not a performance one. So there's no copy issue in the way I described? (that and no issues with garbage collection / memory leaks)

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I don’t think MATLAB would leak memory, no matter what you do in it. There’s also no “garbage collection” the way Java does it. It doesn’t need to. When a variable goes out of scope (eg at the end of the function where it is defined), then it gets deleted. When the last variable to reference a handle is deleted, then the handle is deleted too. This is a straight-forward cleanup process at the end of scopes.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Of course if a handle object can contain a variable that is again a handle object, which makes the straightforward cleanup process a bit more complicated, because now you can have circles of ownership where you can’t delete anything anymore. I don’t know how MATLAB deals with this, I suspect it examines handles used in the function that weren’t deleted to see if they’re only refererend internally.